# regular expression match php

Tags: php, regex

I need to do a regular expression match in php . the case is that .

2 digits before decimal and 2 digits after decimal.

the problem is that it may and may not have decimal and after decimal digits .

how do i write a expression for this ?

Comment: Please give some example content so were know exactly the type of strings you would be dealing with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try:

```
\d{2}(?:\.\d{2})?
```

Comment: i got this..but what is ?: trying to do. is it necessary?

Comment: It is for grouping only, without remembering what is being grouped.